# auth:failed returns as Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON in vercel

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I now deployed my MERN web app via vercel. Unfortunately, I encountered the above error that is actually not existent with my localhost. In which, pinpoints to the line `.then(data =>` of this block of code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/users/profile`, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
      }
    })
     .then(res => res.json())
      // console.log(res.status) added this just to check if it returns 200 and it is

    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)

      if(typeof data._id !== "undefined") {
        setUser({
          id: data._id,
          isAdmin: data.isAdmin
        })
      } else { 
        setUser({
          id: null,
          isAdmin: null
        })
      }
    })
  }, [])
```

I checked my API via Postman and it returns as

```
{
  "auth": "failed"
}
```

It is also the same output as I console.log(). But this is actually an expected output since the error was on my App.js and it doesn't need to logged in yet. I just don't know why it is not returned as JSON and I also try to return it as false either but still return the auth error.

For more reference this is my API route and controller

```
router.get("/profile", auth.verify, (req, res) => {

    const userData = auth.decode(req.headers.authorization)

    if(userData){       
        userController.getProfile({id: userData.id}).then(result=> res.send(result))
    } else {
        res.send(false)
    }
});

module.exports.getProfile = (reqBody) => {  
    return User.findById(reqBody.id).then((result, error) => {
        if(error){          
            return false
        } else {
            if(result == null){
                return false
            } else {                
                result.password = "************"
                return result
            }
        }
    })
};
```

This is the only error I need to resolve to make my web app function correctly. I hope you will help me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have solved my own problem and successfuly deployed my web app via Vercel.

I checked my Vercel app and try other functions such as login and register. It turns out that my API URL is `undefined`. So, I presume that did not clicked the add button in setting environment variables during the deployment.

I created a new deployment with new repository since I did not figured out how to delete my pre-existing deployed app. I now make sure to click the add button once I entered my environment variables and its URL before clicking the Deploy button.